# How to make my text appearing while scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make my text appear when scrolling? I've found this http://www.jqueryrain.com/?HZtLD8hN but I'd like to know how it works. There was a similar question asked but I don't understand it. Can someone explain, or provide examples, how to make this work?

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id = "divToShowHide" class = "BeforeScroll">Content i want to appear while scrolling</div>
```

CSS

```
.BeforeScroll {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: yellow;
}

.AfterScroll {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I has found this but i don't understand it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307555/how-to-make-text-appear-on-scroll-in-html

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://github.com/jjcosgrove/jquery-aniview/blob/master/jquery.aniview.js this is the code behind it to understand it

Comment: Well you don't need **jquery plugin** for that.. Just be aware of this **[`animate.css`](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)**

Comment: Thanks i will look at it.

Comment: you can use animate.css style sheet https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example is this: say some of your content is in a`<div id="appearble_text">` that is at 70% of the total height of the page. `<div id="container">`

Initially you will set `document.getElementById("appearable_text").style.display = "none";`

You can set up a function

```
function OnScroll() {

            var totalHeight = this.offsetHeight; //(this, because container is the caller of the function from the code below)
            if (this.scrollTop || this.scrollTop > totalHeight * 0.7) { //if scrolling reached 70% of height
               document.getElementById("appearable_text").style.display = "block"; 
            }
        }
```

and then use it

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.onscroll = OnScroll;
```

Of course, instead of just suddenly displaying the `<div>` you can fade it in or do all sorts of CSS/JQuery tricks you like.